# Untar (.gz) a file on the as400?

Tags: tar, ibm-midrange

My google fu seems to fail me - or maybe it's just the delightful amount of fantastic information there is available on the IBM Power/iSeries/as400 beast.

In any case, I have a .tar.gz file on this machine.

When I fire up qsh and run `tar -xzvf mytarfile.tar.gz` it doesn't run 'cause there's no `z` flag. And `tar -xvf` tells me that the byte limit has been reached. A *lot*.

Is there a command somewhere on the iseries that I could use to actually untar my file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gz is technically not a tar file - it's a gzip file.  tar -z is a convenience on most *nix platforms that's missing on IBM i.  The notional steps are gzip followed by tar.  I have gunzip on my machine but it's been there so long I can't remember if it's part of the base OS or if I added it on.

- IBM's [Developer Tools for IBM i](http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/pw_com_porting_tools_index) PASE has gzip/gunzip.
- Scott Klement has ported a [version of 7-Zip](http://www.scottklement.com/p7zip/) for PASE.  It works
  on .gz files.
- UCLA [have a site](http://bio.gsi.de/DOCS/AIX/aixpdslib.seas.ucla.edu/categories/file_utilities.html) for AIX binaries that might have what you need.